# BOM Recursive CTE / Parts Explosion. Bug in CTE

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Please take a look at my Recursive CTE in a stored procedure.
The Recursive CTE provides me with a table with:

ComponentId, Name, Total

It does this correctly, however there are some bugs:

1. For this to work, AssemblyId has to be nullable. A component with no assembly (e.g. an orphan) needs to be placed in the db with null for the parent.
2. The query also pulls in the component which I am doing the BOMcte on. e.g. If I search for Computer, I expect it to return something like: 1x Motherboard, 4x Ram, 1x CPU, 1xCase. instead, it returns... 1xComputer, 1x Motherboard, 4x Ram, 1x CPU, 1xCase.
3. Following on from problem 2, we know that 4 ram are required to make a computer. If I run a BOMcte on the RAM, it tells me that 4 are required. It is working the wrong way.

Can anybody help me fix this please?

Ideally, I would like to restructure it as follows:
Pass into the Stored Procedure the ParentId and the recursive query finds all the children and quantity required. If a parent has no children, then the CTE should return an empty table.

Many thanks in advance.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SP_PartExploder
@pid int
AS
/* SET NOCOUNT ON */
WITH BOMcte(ComponentId, Name, Quantity, AssemblyId) 
AS 
(
SELECT b.ComponentID, 
       p.Name,
       b.Quantity, 
       b.AssemblyId 
FROM PartComponents AS b 
INNER JOIN Parts p 
on b.ComponentId = p.PartId 
WHERE b.ComponentId = @pid
UNION ALL 
SELECT b.ComponentID, 
       p.Name,
       b.Quantity, 
       b.AssemblyId 
FROM PartComponents as b 
INNER JOIN Parts p 
ON b.ComponentId = p.PartId 
INNER JOIN BOMcte AS cte 
ON b.AssemblyId = cte.ComponentId 
) 
SELECT ComponentId, Name, sum(Quantity) as Total
FROM BOMcte 
group by ComponentId, Name;
RETURN
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can easily fix it by adding the condition to the outer SELECT like this:

```
...
SELECT ComponentId, Name, sum(Quantity) as Total 
FROM BOMcte  
WHERE ComponentId <> @pid 
group by ComponentId, Name;
```